# Django error when trying to use update_or_create "SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression"

Tags: python, django, django-models

Trying to rewrite an importer for our database and I'm coming across a syntax error I don't really understand. Here's the code for the importer. The line that's causing problems is the last line. `obj, _ = KeywordInContext.objects.update_or_create(main_keyword.word=this_keyword, context=context)`.
On this line of code, I am trying to create a get or create a new `KeywordInContext` object. The field "main_keyword" is a foreignkey to another object called `Keyword`. `Keyword` has a field called "word," and another called "context." So I'm trying to initialize these fields as parameters.

The only other thing to note is `statement['context']` is part of a dictionary (but there's never been issues with this for loop ever and there shouldn't be now...)

```
      for keyword, contextlist in statement['context']:
         print "KEYWORD: ", keyword
         this_keyword, _ = Keyword.objects.get_or_create(word=keyword,) #creating a keyword object
         for context in contextlist:
             obj, _ = KeywordInContext.objects.get_or_create(main_keyword.word=this_keyword)#, context=context)
```

This gives the following error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python-virtualenv/gtr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python-virtualenv/gtr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python-virtualenv/gtr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 208, in fetch_command
        klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python-virtualenv/gtr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 40, in load_command_class
        module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
        __import__(name)
    File "/srv/global-terrorism-research/gtr_site/management/commands/import_statements.py", line 52
        obj, _ = KeywordInContext.objects.get_or_create(main_keyword.word=this_keyword, context="")
  SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

I really... don't know what "keyword" is referring to.

Here's the models.py code for the `KeywordInContext` model and the `Keyword` model, both of which are supposed to be referenced on this line.

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Keyword(models.Model):
   word      = models.CharField(max_length=200)
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class KeywordInContext(models.Model):
   main_keyword = models.ForeignKey(Keyword)
   context = models.ForeignKey(Keyword, related_name='keyword_context', blank=True, null=True)
```

I don't know what this syntactical error means nor what I need to do to fix it.

Could it be tied to the ", _" that's included with the obj variable and the this_keyword variable? I actually am not sure what these characters do.

Comment: you are passing this as an argument: `main_keyword.word=this_keyword` but that isn't syntactically valid.

Comment: I see. Forgot that this_keyword was being set to a Keyword object anyways.